# How to set a feasible start on python mip

Tags: python, mixed-integer-programming

using [python mip](https://docs.python-mip.com/en/latest/classes.html) I have found that unlike gurobi to initialize a feasible model one should supply it to the model and not per variable. But I can't find an example or explanation of what format is that expected to be at.

Could somone explain how do mip variables initialized?

```
import mip
model = mip.Model("example")
var = model.add_var(var_type=BINARY)
# in gurobi var.start = 0 here model.start = ?
```

Answer (score 3):

The format is a list of tuples. The tuples contain vars and their initialization
in this case:

```
import mip
model = mip.Model("example")
var = model.add_var(var_type=BINARY)
model.start = [(var, 1)]
```

Comment: Do I need to mention all variables in the start, or do they get initialized to zero if not mentioned?

Comment: I don't remember, I think it is different depending on the backend. But anyway, this should be a new question